# JPA annotation criteria join

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'd like to know how to force JPA to create inner join select instead of N+1 queries. I have a **generic** DAO using JPA criteria API like (simplified):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<T> pageQuery = cb.createQuery(genericType);
Root<T> root = pageQuery.from(genericType);     
pageQuery.select(root);     
TypedQuery<T> selectQuery = entityManager.createQuery(pageQuery);       
selectQuery.setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(20);        
selectQuery.getResultList();
```

Where domain entities with JPA/Hibernate annotations can contain other entities like:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "arematcd")
public Matcode getMatcode() {
    return this.matcode;
}
```

Do I need to explicitly call `root.fetch("propertyNameOfReferencedEntity");` for all FKs of current type?

**EDIT:**

Workaround based on Ish's suggestion (just replace JPA with Hibernate):

```
Session ss = entityManager.getSession();
Criteria pageQuery = ss.createCriteria(genericType);
pageQuery.setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(20);      
pageQuery.list();
```

Setting `optional=false` in `@ManyToOne` did not help.

Comment: make the relation not nullable? then i'd expect the JPA implementation to do INNER, or at least DataNucleus JPA does. No idea what "@Fetch" is, since not JPA

Comment: @NeilStockton `@Fetch` is _org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch_ it seems it has no effect, I tried to add `nullable=false` to all `@JoinColumn`s in one parent entity, but generated query is still the same (I have not changed columns' nullable type in DB though)

Comment: I know you used JPA-specific way of constructing your Criteria query. How about trying to create the criteria query using Hibernate specific API? Not sure if it will make a difference. Perhaps, it will be able to read this `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)`

Comment: @Ish Just tried to replace JPA criteria with Hibernate criteria and now I have a select with joins, post an answer and I will accept it as a workaround.

Comment: glad it works as workaround. just posted my suggestion as answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using JPA-specific way of constructing your Criteria query, perhaps Hibernate specific annotations were ignored such as `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)`. So I suggest constructing your query using Hibernate specific Criteria API.

Currently, JPA doesn't have support for specific types of fetch strategies like Hibernate does. JPA only has LAZY and EAGER fetch.